# Set the Proxy for a VB-Script

Tags: windows, vbscript, proxy, web, connection

I want to run a VB-Script behind a proxy. The proxy is defined for the system:

[image]

However the Proxy is not applied for my vb-script. If I run the following code:

```
Dim objHttp
Set objHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "GET", "http://www.google.de", False
objHttp.Send
output = objHttp.ResponseText
Set objHttp = Nothing
```

I get a timeout error:

[image]

It seems like the proxy is not used in the script. Is there a posiblitiy to set the proxy manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line

```
objHttp.setProxy 2, "http=myProxyServer:80", ""
```

Syntax:

```
setProxy(ByVal proxySetting As SXH_PROXY_SETTING, [ByVal varProxyServer], [ByVal varBypassList])
```

The  `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP` object also supports proxy credentials if you need.

Syntax:

```
setProxyCredentials(ByVal bstrUserName As String, ByVal bstrPassword As String)
```

Comment: this looks rly good, I will test it tomorrow and give you feedback